# How do I parse this correctly with spirit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6, boost-spirit, greedy

My situation: I'm new to Spirit, I have to use VC6 and am thus using Spirit 1.6.4.

I have a line that looks like this:

```
//The Description;DESCRIPTION;;
```

I want to put the text `DESCRIPTION` in a string if the line starts with `//The Description;`.

I have something that works but looks not that elegant to me:

```
vector<char> vDescription; // std::string doesn't work due to missing ::clear() in VC6's STL implementation
if(parse(chars,
    // Begin grammar
    (
       as_lower_d["//the description;"]
    >> (+~ch_p(';'))[assign(vDescription)]
    ),
    // End grammar
    space_p).hit)
{
    const string desc(vDescription.begin(), vDescription.end());
}
```

I would much more like to assign all printable characters up to the next `';'` but the following won't work because `parse(...).hit == false`

```
parse(chars,
        // Begin grammar
        (
           as_lower_d["//the description;"]
        >> (+print_p)[assign(vDescription)]
        >> ';'
        ),
        // End grammar
        space_p).hit)
```

How do I make it hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using [`confix_p`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/confix.html):

```
confix_p(as_lower_d["//the description;"],
         (+print_p)[assign(vDescription)],
         ch_p(';')
        )
```

It should be equivalent to [Fred's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466802#467316).

The reason your code fails is because `print_p` is *greedy*. The `+print_p` parser will consume characters until it encounters the end of the input or a non-printable character. Semicolon is printable, so `print_p` claims it. Your input gets exhausted, the variable is assigned, and the match fails — there's nothing left for the last semicolon of your parser to match.

Fred's answer constructs a new parser, `(print_p - ';')`, which matches everything `print_p` does, except for semicolons. "Match everything except *X*, and then match *X*" is a common pattern, so `confix_p` is provided as a shortcut for constructing that kind of parser. The documentation suggests using it for parsing C- or Pascal-style comments, but that's not required.

For your code to work, Spirit would need to recognize that the greedy `print_p` matched too much and then *backtrack* to allow matching less. But although Spirit will backtrack, it won't backtrack to the "middle" of what a sub-parser would otherwise greedily match. It will backtrack to the next "choice point," but your grammar doesn't have any. See [*Exhaustive backtracking and greedy RD*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/rationale.html#exhaustive_rd) in the Spirit documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this works, too and looks even better.

I have a small correction though: To get only the text _in_between_ confix_p's opening and closing, the [assign()] action has to be put behind the print_p instead of behind confix_p().

Comment: Ah, you're right. I skimmed over the documentation too fast. It looks wrong at first, but the parser fixes it to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

You're not getting a hit because ';' is matched by print_p.  Try this:

```
parse(chars,
    // Begin grammar
    (
       as_lower_d["//the description;"]
    >> (+(print_p-';'))[assign(vDescription)]
    >> ';'
    ),
    // End grammar
    space_p).hit)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow.
It looks like there is a fundamental misunderstanding on my side then. I assumed the parser would try to match things if possible and not be so lazy...
Do you know what the term for this behaviour is?

Comment: I think the term is "greedy".  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/spirit/doc/faq.html#greedy_rd